# can one commit aveiros after he is dead?

Tags: gezel-stealing

A terminally ill man gives away all the $ from his bank account and then maxes out his credit card on gold bars which he gives to his friends. He correctly estimates that he will die before the purchases show up on the statement. He thus died without ever being chayiv to pay the cc company. The "stealing" from the credit card company only occurs after he is dead. Has he done a sin?

Comment: When you say "Has he done a sin?" do you mean "has he done something wrong?" or "is he culpable in court?"?

Comment: the first one..

Comment: He would already be in a place with the jurisdiction to decide.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Then isn't it obvious that the answer is yes? His estimate of his own mortality doesn't mitigate the financial crime at the moment he commits it.

Comment: But wlhen did he become obligated to pay?

Comment: the ruach who asked to trick achav was punished

Comment: @Clint the title of your question can be answered with two stories in the agadata where a post mortem sin by a dead person is punished accordingly, however they would not address the specific  question in the body.

Comment: can you link me those agaddas?

Answer (score 1):

No, though to answer your updated question via the comments, of course. Creating a debt with the intent of not paying it back is theft. It doesn't matter whether you're caught or not. Sure, it's a clever way of doing it, but it's still stealing.

Comment: Jamezrp, welcome to Mi Yodeya. I hope you'll like the place and decide to stay. Before you post an answer, please read over it several times and make sure it's as clear as possible to the maximum possible number of readers. (The first sentence could use some work.) Still, thanks very much for the thoughtful answer!

Comment: Jamezrp, could you please insert sources for your answer?